# Csv data graphs over multiple days

Tags: csv, logging, graph

I am trying to make graphs with multiple Csv Files, The files are formatted like this;

```
file 1
2019-10-14,00:10:12,0,21.3,64.0
2019-10-14,00:11:17,0,21.3,63.0
2019-10-14,00:11:18,0,21.3,64.0
2019-10-14,00:11:46,0,21.2,63.0

file 2
2019-10-15,00:00:01,0,22.7,64.0
2019-10-15,00:00:04,0,22.6,64.0
2019-10-15,00:00:05,0,22.7,64.0
2019-10-15,00:00:08,0,22.6,64.0
```

I am using a Raspberry pi, coded in python, to log this data. from left to right it is "Date, Time, Light, Temp, Humidity"

Every day i have over 10.000 Samples. I can make pretty accurate daily graphs using the dot plot in excel. But i would like to know, is there an easy way to make a week based graph? using both the date and the time? Or a program where I can upload these files and it makes the graphs for me?

So i made some Macro's in excel making the daily graphs for me, this makes stuff a lot easier, but its still not a solution to my problem.

Comment: Currently the way I'm doing this is by creating the graphs of every day(file) seperately in excel, then i make a png of the graphs and I paste the images in paint next to each other. There has te be an easier way right?